# Textmate: cannot find page up for macbook keyboard

Tags: textmate

Using a macbook keyboard (which means I do not have the 'page up' button) I cannot figure out what the pageUp keybinding is or how to bind ctrl+u to the pageUp action.

My first attempt was to add this to my KeyBindings.dict file:

```
{
    "^u"  = "pageUp:";
}
```

That didn't work, so I tried to define pageUp: in "settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> application shortcuts" and then created one for textmate using 'pageUp' and 'pageUp:' as the 'Menu Title' option (there is no menu option for textmate that I can see so I was kind of guessing here).

Basically, what is the opposite of ctrl+v? Or if it does not exist for this keyboard, how can I bind ctrl+u to page up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have changed something with that keybindings file. fn-up arrow should page up and fn-down arrow should page down. The cursor doesn't move with these however, just the screen. I just accidentally found that Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down work the same way in TextMate. Playing around a bit, I also found that fn-Opt-Up and fn-Opt-Down will page up and page down while also moving the cursor.

Comment: fn+opt+up arrow, that is what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: +1  Wow, the fn-opt-up and fn-opt-down is what I have needed for 9 months (duration of my macos misadventures)

Comment: btw What the heck is fn-up and fn-down supposed to do anyways .. As soon as one types, you lose the position of the cursor: seems useless.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see right away the binding for it, but I do know that on MacBook's, fn + up / down arrow keys gives you page up / page down functionality.

Comment: I might have my terms wrong in saying I want pageUp functionality so let me clarify: I want the cursor to jump up the height of 1 screen view. fn+up arrow will move the cursor to the top or bottom of the file, so that is not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: cmd+up arrow jumps to the top, but fn+up arrow does a page-up like he says.

Comment: Of all the dumb oversights. Thanks for pointing out I was using cmd and not fn. This is most of what I am looking for, but as Chuck points out below, the cursor does not follow which kind of defeats the purpose. What I wanted was fn+opt+up arrow.